# Echo category name once per id

Tags: php, mysql

I have a query `SELECT id, title, imagename FROM cat JOIN images ON id=id`
I want to echo only once title per category and then 3 images. And then the same with next category.

Tables layout:

```
Cat Table
id title

Images Table
id imagename
```

The final result should look like this:

```
Title

Imagename Imagename Imagename

Title

Imagename Imagename Imagename
```

The query is printed using foreach cycle as object `($this->results as $result ) { echo $result->title; }` etc..

Also I'm interested if there are other ways (queries?) of getting the same results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to keep track of the current title and only echo a title when it is different from the current one:

```
$title = '';
// loop
  ...
  if ($result->title !== $title)
  {
    echo $result->title;
    $title = $result->title;
  }
  ...
// end loop
```

Note that you do need to `ORDER BY title` in your query as you could get the same title again later on if you don't.

Comment: Thanks for answer guys. This looks like a working method, but i wonder if there's a different approach (use of different query or something)?

Comment: @user1876234 No, you cannot get a tree-like structure directly from mysql. The result will always be a one-dimensional record set.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a variable like `$prevTitle` and if the current title matches the previous title, don't echo it. This will ensure only the new titles would be echoed, and only once. Of course, that would mean that your object would have to be sorted/grouped by titles in order not to have results like

> title1
>
> title1
>
> title2
>
> title1

because that would echo the title 1 twice.